# Youtube V3 api Load Multiple Playlists

Tags: api, youtube, playlist

I just want to load multiple playlists based on multiple playlistID's, the problem is playlistid can insert only not multiple comma seperated.

```
$PlylistIds = 'PLbVdwtmx18stbIbCu-bONmOSP4JLOPF9I, PL7668E699EA971785';

$response = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails,snippet&playlistId=$PlylistIds&maxResults=5&key=MYAPIKEY");
$searchResponse = json_decode($response,true);
print_r($searchResponse);
```

When i sent 1 playlist id it works but when i add two playlist ids its stop returning json result.

I don't want to use LOOP everytime to send request to google server, is it possible to load multiple playlistids at one request, instead of using multiple loops.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone here to help me.

Comment: Need help plz this is very confusing.

Comment: I think it is not possible, we have to call separate call for the other playlist and merge both files to show in a list, I call do it in this way that I will create an array of all the playlistss, then I will call for loop and get all the items of the multiple playlists one by one, add all the items to one list, and at last I will show the list items.

Comment: Hey @Abdullah, did you manage to find out how to do this most efficiently? I am struggling with the same problem and I don't feel like sending hundreds, maybe even thousands of requests everyday.